# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEBUG, but settings are not configured

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

**django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEBUG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.**

manage.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'alumni_portal.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

setting.py

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
BASE_DIR2 = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR2,'templates')
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR2, 'static')


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-nj@^0^n%be!u=8!o5ui7efi*b7)iad2(jgw06^flv=z4i$z%7_'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'portal',
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django_social_share',
    'import_export',
]

# CKEDITOR_UPLOADER_PATH = 'media/'

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'alumni_portal.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'alumni_portal.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',  
        'NAME': 'dbs',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.2',
        'PORT': '3300',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'Jamal@123',
        'OPTIONS': {
        'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'",
        'init_command': "set FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;",

        }
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    STATIC_DIR
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "/static")

MEDIA_URL = '/uploads/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR2, 'uploads')
# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'portal.User'
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'dashboard'

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'height': '100%', 
        'width': '100%', 
    },
}

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '19ita57@karpagamtech.ac.in'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'Jamal@123'
```

**Guys can help me to solve this error**
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEBUG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Comment: Please add more details about what you are trying to do and in what stage the error occurs.

Comment: Does this File `{root}/alumni_portal/settings.py` exist + look all good?- what type of set up are you running in, is this a Windows 10 Dev Env or an Ubuntu VM Prod Env or something else?

Comment: When you run the server, django looks for the settings file but it is not there

Answer (score 0):

> Generally, when working on a single Django project, it’s easier to use `manage.py` than `django-admin`. If you need to switch between multiple Django settings files, use `django-admin` with `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` or the `--settings` command line option.

[Django 4.2 Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-and-manage-py)

So, just use the command `python3 manage.py runserver` instead of `django-admin runserver`.